# How can i use Drag and drop plugins in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, nuxt.js

I am looking for a tutorial that teaches me how to implement the drag and drop effect like
[Vue-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable)
[smooth-dnd](https://kutlugsahin.github.io/vue-smooth-dnd/#/cards) in a project of Nuxtjs. For styling, I am using Tailwind CSS.

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Tried some packages ?

Comment: Thanks, @kissu for your answer. Actually, I am new in Nuxt js and don't know how to configure plugins in Nuxt project.

Comment: Check this video: https://youtu.be/gAqcW51NwTE

Comment: Yes! It helped me. And I Worked on your guideline. See Here I made it possible.https://github.com/Abdurrahman-Alizada/EaseM.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking into smooth drag&drop, you can install the [vue-smooth-dnd](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd) package by going through [nuxt plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/).

```js
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-smooth-dnd.js']
}
```

That way, it could then be used exactly [as show in the docs](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd#vue).

---

#### EDIT

Actually, it looks like you can directly use it as (in your `.vue` component)

```js
import { Container, Draggable } from "vue-smooth-dnd"
```

With no more configuration needed. It will be scoped per component and will not explode size-wise.